# Alternative that does the same as dotimes but will return something other than nil

Tags: vector, clojure

I am needing something similar to dotimes in clojure but will allow me to return something at the end other than nil. Have not found anything myself but need it to be able to take in a vector, do some formatting on each element then cons that element onto a new vector. Any help would be great. Thanks

```
(defn single-in-vec [num]
  (if (symbol? num)
      (into [] (cons num ()))
       num)
 )


(defn add-in-vec [tree newtree]
  (dotimes [n 5] (cons  (single-in-vec (nth tree n)) newtree ))
  newtree)
```

This is what I am inputting in.

```
(add-in-vec '[A B C [D E F] [G H I]] '[ ])
```

This is the expected output

```
[[A] [B] [C] [D E F] [G H I]]
```

Comment: Can you post a sample input and expected output?

Comment: If you need to return something, you likely shouldn't be using `doseq` in the first place. A `loop` or `reduce` would likely be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You should use something like [`reduce`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce):

```
(defn single-in-vec [num]
  (if (symbol? num)
    (into [] (cons num ()))
    num))

(defn add-in-vec [tree newtree]
  (reduce (fn [acc elem]
            (conj acc (single-in-vec (nth tree elem)) ))
          newtree
          (range 5)))

(add-in-vec '[A B C [D E F] [G H I]] '[])
=> [[A] [B] [C] [D E F] [G H I]]
```

Let's go over some issues in your original example:

```
(defn add-in-vec [tree newtree]
  (dotimes [n 5] (cons  (single-in-vec (nth tree n)) newtree ))
  newtree)
```

1. `dotimes` is generally for *side-effects* but you don't need any here. You just want to update your `newtree` five times and return the final state of it.
2. The final return value is `newtree`, but this will always be the *original input value* because the `dotimes` form has not mutated it. All its changes have been lost to the void.
3. `cons` will produce output in an order opposite of what you want. `conj` will add to the end of a vector.

Answer (score 1):

in addition, the thing you are trying to do is idiomatically done with mapping:

```
(defn wrap-sym [x]
  (if (symbol? x) [x] x))

user> (mapv wrap-sym '[A B C [D E F] [G H I]])
;;=> [[A] [B] [C] [D E F] [G H I]]
```

but first of all you really need to get some proper introductory reading on how things are idiomatically done in clojure (and in functional programming languages at all)

my suggestion is [clojure for the brave and true](https://www.braveclojure.com/clojure-for-the-brave-and-true/)

Answer (score 1):

I would just use the `for` statement:

```
(defn add-in-vec [in-vec]
  (vec
    (for [item in-vec]
      (if (symbol? item)
        [item]
        item))))

(add-in-vec '[A B C [D E F] [G H I]])  =>  [[A] [B] [C] [D E F] [G H I]]
```

You may not need the `(vec ...)` wrapper. The `for` returns a lazy sequence, and `vec` converts it (eagerly) into a vector.